# Run tests before sbt dist in sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager, sbt-plugin

I don't wanna create any deployable without running tests. Is there anyway in sbt-native-packager / sbt where I could run sbt test in inside sbt dist, which would fail when any test fails?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

## Create a command alias

This is my recommended approach as it is very explicit, easy to understand and extend. In your build.sbt add

```
addCommandAlias("buildDist", ";  compile ; test ; dist")
```

Now you can call `sbt buildDist`

## Depend on test

You can add dependencies between tasks. In your build.sbt

```
dist := (dist dependsOn test).value
```

This will add the test task as a dependency

Cheers,
Muki